# How can I get Chromium (Chrome) DevTools' NodeJS inspector to properly expand complex objects which have been console.log()'d?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I am using nodejs to retrieve a large and complex object (a JSON version of a big reddit thread), and I'm using `chrome://inspect` to connect DevTools to node.  I'm running the script like so:

```
nodejs --inspect-brk main.js
```

When I console.log() the parsed JSON, DevTools collapses the data structure in the console, and displays it as such:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Pressing the arrow which normally expands objects in console does not expand it.

Being able to explore this object in a pretty way, collapsing and expanding different parts of it as I go was the point of the Inspector in the first place, therefore other solutions such as JSON.stringify(), or just viewing the massive wall of text in the terminal window are not acceptable.

Chromium version 79.0.3945.79, Nodejs v8.10.0, on Mint 19.3.

Very likely answers pertaining to Chrome will work for Chromium.

Comment: If you modify the object afterwards, devtools won't remember the old value so you need to print a **cloned object** e.g. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: I don't believe the object is being modified after.

Comment: There is simply no other explanation for the inability to expand the output.

Comment: Well, I tried it in both the browser and node, and the identical code works in the browser, but not when run from node.  I think I should make a new post now that I have proof of concept code.

Comment: Aha, I see.  It's because execution had *finished*.   That's what the problem was.  Apparently when that happens data is destroyed.  The solution was to place a breakpoints on the last curly brace.